# SharePoint 2010 Webservice: URL could not be found

Tags: web-services, error

Always getting the following error while trying to create a spsite-object:

> The Web application "http://myApplicationURL/" at could not be found.
>   Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be
>   serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a
>   new request URL mapping to the intended application.

The webservice should access the local SharePoint-Application which does work in a browser.
First it seems like a common problem, but tried all the web-suggested solutions:

- compiling as "any platform" or x64
- using .Net 3.5
- starting as farm administrator / don't start as farm administrator
- trying the published version of the webservice instead of debugging in VS2010
- modifying: regedit DisableLoopBackCheck to 1, means I'm able to log in locally to the application/the other applications
- tried to access a different application on the same server -> same problem
- used elevated privileges
- starting VS2010 with "ADMIN"-Privileges
- adding the starting user (is farm admin) to WSS_ADMIN_WPG windows user group
- users are fully privileged on SQL content database
- users are site collection as well

what else could be wrong?

Here some code, it's simple as that:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://test-sharepoint.myApp.local"))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code pls. Exception makes no sense either unless you manually retyped it : The Web application "http://myApplicationURL/" >>> at <<< could not be found

Comment: Also, another thing you're not mentioning above is whether you're executing account has Site collection rights. I know you're saying you're running as Farm Admin, but that DOES NOT give you Site col admin rights be default. Just make sure of this as well.

Comment: I am also getting the SAME Error when I try to Use the same CODE in ASP.NET WebService , But the Same Piece of code able to Produce the Output in Sample Console Applciation. Why its behaving like this. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to set the AppPool for the WebService: I set it to the same AppPool that the SharePoint application had. It started to work immediately - even if the original AppPool does have the same configurations as the SP2010-AppPool has...

To debug the WebService, just connect the VisualStudio-Debugger to the w3wp.exe-process.

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from Stefan GoBner's Blog:

Here are the most common reasons this error can occur:

> 1. The code is executed on a different machine - The SharePoint object model (except the Client API) requires to be run on the
>      SharePoint server itself. It is not possible to run the application on
>      a server which is not within the same SharePoint farm the code is
>      trying to access.
>
>    1. Insufficient Rights on the site collection - The code is executed in context of an account which does not have read permission
>         on the site collection
>    2. Incorrect Url being used - Verify that the site works correct in a browser and double check that the server is correct registered in
>         the AAM settings
>    3. Incorrect bitness - The SharePoint object model needs to be executed with the same bitness as the operating system. That means you
>         cannot use the SharePoint object model in a 32-bit application if the
>         Operating System and SharePoint are installed as 64-bit version.
>         Ensure to compile the project using the correct bitness (64-bit on a
>         64-bit machine vs. 32-bit on a 32-bit machine)
>    4. Incorrect .NET framework version -  Ensure that the project is configured to use .NET 3.5. .NET 4.0 cannot be used with the current
>         versions of SharePoint

Comment: Did you notice that I was talking about the SPSite-Object? I don't need the Service Reference for creating SPSite-Objects!

Comment: Do you have SharePoint installed on the machine that you are doing the development on?

Comment: Yes exactly on the same machine...

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Please read my question carefully, all these points are already covered in the question!

Comment: try localhost instead of the default zone for `SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(@"http://localhost");`

Comment: Localhost does not exist as a SharePoint site. I'm working with alternate access mapping and host headers because there are several site collections on the server.

Comment: Are you using the default zone URL? Is your default zone URL set to `http://machinename:port` ?

Comment: It's not a problem of SharePoint configuration. If I create a console app, I'm able to access exactly this address, so there is no AAM/Zoning-Problem...

Comment: You have db_owner rights on the **CONFIG** database? Check this thread out: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-GB/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/f58cc9c9-2f7a-4bd8-b199-857629fea90e

Comment: Yes, the user is db_owner on CONFIG and the Content Database. I don't think that the problem is coming from SharePoint itself, as I mentioned above, I was able to access the platform by a console application - using the same piece of code that I wrote in the question...